# iPhone Programming: Deactivate spell check in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, spell-checking

UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo didn't work for me.

I'm working on a crossword app for the iPhone.
The questions are in UITextViews and I use UITextFields for the User-Input of each letter.
By touching a question(UITextView), the TextField for the first answer char becomesFirstResponder.

It all works fine but the UITextViews are still spell checking and mark the wrong words in the question,
even if I set them UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo .

```
//init of my Riddle-Class

...

for (int i = 0; i < theQuestionSet.questionCount; i++) {

    Question *myQuestion = [theQuestionSet.questionArray objectAtIndex:i];
    int fieldPosition = theQuestionSet.xSize * myQuestion.fragePos.y + myQuestion.fragePos.x;
 CrosswordTextField *myQuestionCell = [crosswordCells objectAtIndex:fieldPosition];
 questionFontSize = 6;
 CGRect textViewRect = myQuestionCell.frame;

 UITextView *newView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textViewRect];
 newView.text = myQuestion.frageKurzerText;
 newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.5 green: 0.5 blue: 0.5 alpha: 0.0 ];
 newView.scrollEnabled = NO;
 newView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [newView setDelegate:self];
 newView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
 newView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 newView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:questionFontSize];
 newView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
 [textViews addObject:newView];
 [zoomView addSubview:newView];
 [newView release];
}

...

//UITextView delegate methode in my Riddle-Class

-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

     textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;  

     for (int i = 0; i < [questionSet.questionArray count]; i++) {
      if ([[[questionSet.questionArray objectAtIndex:i] frageKurzerText] isEqualToString:textView.text]) {
        CrosswordTextField *tField = [self textfieldForPosition:
            [[questionSet.questionArray objectAtIndex:i] antwortPos]]; 
        markIsWagrecht = [[questionSet.questionArray objectAtIndex:i] wagrecht];
        if ([tField isFirstResponder]) [tField resignFirstResponder];
             [tField becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
      }
 }
 return NO;
}
```

I don't call UITextView on any other place.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. The solution is very simple but not documented: You can only change the properties defined in the `UITextInputTraits` protocol while the `UITextView` in question is NOT the first responder. The following lines fixed it for me:

```
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];
self.textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Note, if disabling spellcheck too (red underline), you will need to force a UI-update to get rid of the red squiggly line. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958597/2057171

Answer (score 8):

One potentially-helpful tip following from [Engin Kurutepe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306715/engin-kurutepe)'s answer:

If you have subclassed UITextView, you can override the `UITextInputTraits` in the subclass implementation of `becomeFirstResponder`, something like this:

```
-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    self.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
    self.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

There is then no need to explicitly `resign`/`becomeFirstResponder` around your trait changes.

Answer (score 3):

## Important

Disabling spell check will **NOT** update the UI of the red-line until the text itself is also updated. Simply setting the spellCheck to NO is not enough.

To force a UI update, set the spellcheck property to NO, then toggle the text blank then back, like so:

```
_textView.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;

NSString *currentText = _textView.text;
NSAttributedString *currentAttributedText = _textView.attributedText;
_textView.text = @"";
_textView.attributedText = [NSAttributedString new];
_textView.text = currentText;
if (currentAttributedText.length > 0) {
    _textView.attributedText = currentAttributedText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution but it's not really how it should be.
If someone knows something better, please tell me.

The autocorrection executes, after the first touche.
So I alloc a new UITextView and set him like the touched TextView.
Then I replace the touched textView with my new TextView.
So every UITextView instance could only be touched once and disappears. :)

```
//UITextView delegate method in my Riddle-Class

-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    ...CODE FROM FIRST POST HERE...

    // ADDED CODE:
    for (int i = 0; i < [textViews count]; i++) {
        if (textView == [textViews objectAtIndex:i]) {
            UITextView *trickyTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textView.frame];
            trickyTextView.text = textView.text;
            trickyTextView.font = textView.font;
            trickyTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            trickyTextView.textColor = textView.textColor;
            trickyTextView.backgroundColor = textView.backgroundColor;
            trickyTextView.delegate = self;
            trickyTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            [textViews replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:trickyTextView];
            [textView removeFromSuperview];
            [zoomView addSubview:trickyTextView];
            [trickyTextView release];
            break;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```