# How to programmatically turn off Auto Correction in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Programming: Deactivate spell check in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318827/iphone-programming-deactivate-spell-check-in-uitextview)

I am creating a spelling quiz app.

When I type in text in textbox, because auto-correction is ON it shows the correct answer.

I would like to do either of following:
(a) Programatically turn OFF Auto-Correction OR
(b) Give user the option to manually turn OFF Auto-Correction within the app.

Please let me know solution to either of above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the following property:

```
myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; //in ios 8 use UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo.
```

As defined in the `UITextInputTraits` protocol [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)

Comment: Hello @Olly, How we can enable the same option for NSTextfield?

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off auto correction by

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

and can turn on by

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 2):

For a UITextField you can set the 'Correction' to YES or NO through Interface Builder/Storyboard (near Capitalization and Keyboard Type), to set it programatically you can use:

```
UITextField *yourTextField;
yourTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` and `UITextField` both implement the UITextInputTraits protocol. As such, they both have a property `autocorrectionType`, which is itself of type `UITextAutocorrectionType`. The default value for this property is on. You can set it to be `UITextAutocorrectiontypeNo` in your code (probably when you create the view), which will disable any autocorrection.