# Disable autosuggest

Tags: objective-c, ios7

My textfield name is `searchtextfeild`.
When I type anything, it autosuggests as in the given picture.

[image]

Now, I simply do not want to show this autosuggest. I want to disable it.

I tried,

```
searchtextfeild.autoautocorrectionType = FALSE;
```

Strange thing is though `searchtextfeild` is textfield, it does not have property `autoautocorrectionType`.
Anyway, how can I disable this autosuggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically turn off Auto Correction in iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789594/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-auto-correction-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Actually I found solution. My searchfeild was using library. And autocorrectiontype works

Comment: how can i remove this question ?

Comment: There should be a delete button just below the question tags (objective-c and ios7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocorrectionType` property has type `UITextAutocorrectionType` which is enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITextAutocorrectionType) {
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes,
};
```

So you just need to do

```
searchtextfeild.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this please:

```
searchtextfeild.autocorrectionType = TRUE;
```

For some strange reason it works for me.